# posting multi-part form data with php curl

Tags: php, curl

> ```
> (multipart/Form data)
> Files - array
> Answer - string
> ```

```
        $postData = array();
        $postData["Answer"] = $text;
        
        foreach ($images as $index => $file) {
            $postData['Files[' . $index . ']'] = curl_file_create(
                $file,
                $functions->mime_type($file),
                pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME)
            );
        }
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('merchantId:98765431'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_URL ,"https://...");
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Trying to post a multi form data. Request fails and prints an error "post field "Answer" is invalid". Can you help?

Comment: Do not specify the `Content-Type` header yourself, let cURL handle it. (The one you specified yourself does not contain any `boundary` value, but that is necessary for the receiver to be able to parse the multipart request body correctly.)

Comment: Removed it. Still getting the code 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: Not sure you need CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST either.

Comment: @CBroe Removing CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST worked, but only sends the Answer field, won't send files. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Good answer

For posting multipart with curl you need to use header like this

```
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");
```

```
if (isset($_POST['btnUpload'])){
    $url = "URL_PATH of upload.php"; // e.g. request URL http://localhost/myuploader/upload.php
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    if ($filedata != ''){
        $headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); // cURL headers for file uploading
        $postfields = array("filedata" => "@$filedata", "filename" => $filename);
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
            CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        ); // cURL options
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        curl_exec($ch);
        if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            if ($info['http_code'] == 200)
                $errmsg = "File uploaded successfully";
        } else {
            $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    } else {
        $errmsg = "Please select the file";
    }
}
```

For your case just add `"Content-Type:multipart/form-data"` to your function

```
$postData = array();
$postData["Answer"] = $text;

foreach ($images as $index => $file) {
    $postData['Files[' . $index . ']'] = curl_file_create(
        $file,
        $functions->mime_type($file),
        pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME)
    );
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data",'merchantId:98765431')); //HERE THE ADD
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_URL ,"https://...");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```